# PuTTY - Software Caused Connection Abort

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I am trying to connect to my server through PuTTY from my Windows 7. After I have typed in the website (server) address and port number. The terminal popped up and freezes until it appears the error message:

```
 Software Caused Connection Abort
```

I could not even have the chance to type in my password, like I can for the time from I downloaded PuTTY.

Comment: Try: Win+R -> cmd -> `telnet example.com 22` where `example.com` is your hostname and `22` is your port number. What is the output?If it's SSH banner (`SSH-X.X-OpenSSH_X.X` etc.) the server is up. Do you have access to other computer or phone with Android (and some SSH app) that you can test if you have connection? If you don't have `telnet` installed, install in in add/remove software->windows components or try to use PuTTy to telnet to your SSH port. Are you sure that website's server is up and not uses some proxy like Cloudflare? You can also try to log in directly from hosting control.

Comment: The tech service was successful on using ssh into my server, and I am not aware if the server is using proxies.

Comment: Try to disable Windows Firewall, if that doesn't help, try to login to your router and disable firewall there.

Comment: @hex [Refer to the first comment] I have used `telnet` and nothing happened until return to the original `cmd.exe` screen.

Comment: If your server uses standard `22` port, try maybe to use PuTTy to login to some other SSH server, like `sdf.org` on port 22. If that also don't work (no `login: ` prompt), this means that you have blocked this port somewhere (or it is blocked by your ISP).

Comment: @hex The connection to `sdf.org` through my `cmd.exe` works.

Comment: Then something is probably wrong with your server, and not your local PC. Can you... just restart it?

Comment: @hex That's weird, provided that the tech service has successfully use ssh into my server...

Comment: Do you have access to recovery console or direct SSH in your hosting control panel?

Comment: I don't have access thru recovery console or direct SSH in my hosting control panel